# My Div Keeps Popping Up After User Accepts

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have created a notice that is supposed to pop up and ask the user if they agree to the privacy terms. If they do, a cookie should be set where it doesn't pop up again for a time period. The problem is for some users it continues to pop up after they click OK/Accept. If the user or myself does a 'hard refresh' (clear cash) it seems the function works.

Here's the javascript

```
function checkCookie() {
  
  if (document.cookie.indexOf("accpttrms") <= 0) {
      document.getElementById("disclaimer").style.display = "block";      
      } else {
      document.getElementById("disclaimer").style.display = "none";
    }  
}

function setCookie() {
  
  if (document.cookie.indexOf("accpttrms") <= 0) {    
      document.cookie = "accpttrms=yes";      
      var x = document.getElementById("disclaimer");
      x.style.display = "none";
    }   
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<body onload="checkCookie()">

  <section id="disclaimer" style="display:none;">
    <div class="disholder">
    
      <h4>PLEASE REVIEW OUR UPDATED PRIVACY & COOKIES NOTICE</h4>
      <p>This site uses cookies and similar technologies...
        <a href="/privacy-policy/">Read our updated Privacy &amp; Cookies Notice</a> to learn more.
      </p>  
      <div><a href="#" onclick="setCookie()">I ACCEPT</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Most probably these users are blocking the cookies. Also, why are you checking if `indexOf <= 0`? What if it's equal to 0?

Comment: Try using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) instead of cookies

Answer (score 0):

I think your real problem is that the `indexOf` method is returning exactly 0. So, you only need to replace the `<=` with `<`.

Comment: Thank you adripanico. I tried different variations of chaning <= to < within the script but it still didn't work. As I click accept, and go to the next page it displays again. I used private windows too in 3 browsers.

Comment: You can set a cookie in private navigation, but it will be removed as soon as you close the browser.